# c++ inserting elements at the end of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, size

I am experiencing a problem with the vector container. I am trying to improve the performance of inserting a lot of elements into one vector.

Basically I am using vector::reserve to expand my vector _children if needed:

```
if (_children.capacity() == _children.size())
{
     _children.reserve(_children.size() * 2);
}
```

and using vector::at() to insert a new element at the end of _children instead of vector::push_back():

```
_children.at(_children.size()) = child;
```

_children has already one element in it, so the first element should be inserted at position 1, and the capacity at this time is 2.

Despite this, an out_of_range error is thrown. Can someone explain to me, what I misunderstood here? Is it not possible to just insert an extra element even though the chosen position is less than the vector capacity? I can post some more code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

/mads

Comment: Your compiler's implementation of `vector` probably already doubles allocated memory when more is needed.  `reserve` is more for when you know an upper bound on the vector size before adding any data.

Comment: Hello, Mads. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). And, please upvote any answers that helped you, and accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increasing the capacity doesn't increase the number of elements in the vector. It simply ensures that the vector has capacity to grow up to the required size without having to reallocate memory. I.e., you still need to call `push_back()`.

Mind you, calling `reserve()` to increase capacity geometrically is a waste of effort. `std::vector` already does this.

Comment: I'd +2 if I could, because both paragraphs are right, and needed to be said.

Comment: Yes of course you are right. I dont know what I was thinking. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This causes accesses out of bounds. Reserving memory does not affect the size of the vector.

Basically, you are doing manually what `push_back` does internally. Why do you think it would be any more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Neither `at` nor `reserve` increase the size of the vector (the latter increases the **capacity** but not the **size**).

Also, your attempted optimization is almost certainly redundant; you should simply `push_back` the elements into the array and rely on `std::vector` to expand its capacity in an intelligent manner.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `at()` is for. `at()` is a checked version of `[]`, i.e. accessing an element. But `reserve()` does not change the number of elements.

You should just use `reserve()` followed by `push_back` or `emplace_back` or `insert` (at the end); all those will be efficient, since they will not cause reallocations if you stay under the capacity limit.

Note that the vector *already* behaves exactly like you do manually: When it reaches capacity, it resizes the allocated memory to a multiple of the current size. This is mandated by the requirement that adding elements have amortized constant time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between the **capacity** and the **size**. You can only assign within size, and reserve only affects the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::reserve` is only internally reserving space but is not constructing objects and is not changing the external size of the vector. If you use reserve you need to use `push_back`.
Additionally `vector::at` does range checking, which makes it a lot slower compared to `vector::operator[]`.

What you are doing is trying to mimic part of the behaviour vector already implements internally. It is going to expand by its size by a certain factor (usually around 1.5 or 2) every time it runs out of space. If you know that you are pushing back many objects and only want one reallocation use:

```
vec.reserve(vec.size() + nbElementsToAdd);
```

If you are not adding enough elements this is potentially worse than the default behaviour of `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The capacity of a vector is not the number of elements it has, but the number of elements it can hold without allocating more memory. The capacity is equal to or larger than the number of elements in the vector.

In your example, `_children.size()` is 1, but there is no element at position 1. You can only use assignment to replace existing elements, not for adding new ones. Per definition, the last element is at `_children.at(_children.size()-1)`.

The correct way is just to use `push_back()`, which is highly optimized, and faster than inserting at an index. If you know beforehand how many elements you want to add, you can of course use `reserve()` as an optimization.

It's not necessary to call reserve manually, as the `vector` will automatically resize the internal storage if neccessary. Actually I believe what you do in your example is similar what the vector does internally anyway - when it reaches the capacity, reserve twice the current size.

See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/capacity/